# cassandra not working on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I followed instruction  for installing cassandra:
http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html

then i checked for cassandra service and it is active but when i try `nodetool status` it throws following error:

error: null
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getDiskFailurePolicy(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1955)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector.inspectThrowable(JVMStabilityInspector.java:82)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.(FileUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.getToolsOutputDirectory(FBUtilities.java:869)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.printHistory(NodeTool.java:200)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:168)

moreover when i run `cqlsh 127.0.0.1:9042` it throws this:

error: null
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getDiskFailurePolicy(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1955)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector.inspectThrowable(JVMStabilityInspector.java:82)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.(FileUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.getToolsOutputDirectory(FBUtilities.java:869)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.printHistory(NodeTool.java:200)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:168)

Comment: Are you running nodetool on the node where cassandra is running? At a guess, I'd say that nodetool can't find cassandra.yaml because all getDiskFailurePolicy does is return conf.disk_failure_policy. conf is set after cassandra.yaml is loaded.

Comment: everything is on a single machine, additionally i cannot connect to cassandra using cqlsh or any other driver.

Comment: maybe a crazy question, what version of java are you using? cassandra requires java8, I believe